# How to restart heroku app without killing unfinished celery tasks

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery

I have a django web application on heroku in which several celery tasks may be running in the background. Redis is used as a broker.

The problem is, that when I restart the heroku application either with `heroku restart` or by deploying with `heroku container:release` while some tasks are being executed, they are killed with SIGTERM which means the tasks are never finished.

```
2018-11-23T19:35:24.506833+00:00 heroku[beat.1]: Restarting
2018-11-23T19:35:24.507645+00:00 heroku[beat.1]: State changed from up to starting
2018-11-23T19:35:24.517551+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2018-11-23T19:35:24.518013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2018-11-23T19:35:24.528684+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Restarting
2018-11-23T19:35:24.529175+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2018-11-23T19:35:24.952139+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2018-11-23T19:35:24.952156+00:00 app[worker.1]: worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
2018-11-23T19:35:24.949622+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-11-23T19:35:24.996307+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-11-23T19:35:25.456920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-11-23T19:35:25.480748+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-23 19:35:25 +0000] [16] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2018-11-23T19:35:25.481026+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-23 19:35:25 +0000] [19] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19)
2018-11-23T19:35:25.481491+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-23 19:35:25 +0000] [20] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 20)
2018-11-23T19:35:25.481519+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-23 19:35:25 +0000] [21] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 21)
2018-11-23T19:35:25.623274+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-11-23T19:35:25.816061+00:00 heroku[beat.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-11-23T19:35:25.928498+00:00 heroku[beat.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

From what I found on the internet, *the warm shutdown caused by SIGTERM should wait for tasks to finish*, but it is not happening. They are just killed.

- Why is that?
- Do I have to configure something to achieve the desired behaviour? Or is it just not working?

With the current behaviour I'm am not sure how to do deployment, unless I check somehow no tasks are running and then I do the restart.

Comment: Probably makes more sense to post this as a comment since it doesn't explain how to restart heroku without killing celery tasks, but offers a workaround:

You can configure Celery and enable `task_acks_late` and `task_reject_on_worker_lost`

This will make sure that the queue is receiving and ack signal from celery only once the task is completed and, in case the worker is killed `task_reject_on_worker_lost` will make sure that the message is re-queued, not marked as completed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunatelly this doesn't seem to be working with redis for some readon, only with rabbitmq (https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3541). The link offers some suggestions too, this one seems to be working for me: https://gist.github.com/mlavin/6671079

Comment: So after some testing, the above does not work perfectly either. The tasks are sometimes restored after heroku restartw, but sometimes the heroku needs to be restarted several times before the tasks are rescheduled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is heroku sending the wrong signal to celery, to it doesn't to the warm shutdown and is killed for restarting.

Beginning with Celery 4 (if I remember correctly) you can tell celery to listen to a different signal. For us this worked.

Change your `Procfile` to include `REMAP_SIGTERM=SIGQUIT` for your worker process:

```
celeryworker: REMAP_SIGTERM=SIGQUIT  celery -A testproject worker
```

This will have celery for example re-queue tasks that were queued locally.

To keep in mind: 
there still is a hard kill after something like 10 or 20 seconds. So if you have tasks that run longer you have to tweak `acks_late`.